# Почему в цикле else срабатывает вместе с if в python

Tags: python, if, dict

**Ребят всем спасибо за ответы. программирование это сложная история, но с таким комьюнити, мне не страшно в нее погружаться! еще раз всем спасибо!!!**

Сильно не пинайте, только начал изучать язык и вот с этой задачкой всю голову уже себе сломал...
если пишу только оператор if, все работает как и должно, нет никаких лишних повторений, отображается правильный результат.
но как только добавляю else чтобы указать пользователю на неправильные или несуществующие данные, то все ломается. выглядит так, будто else выполняется одновременно или вообще раньше чем сам if.
Где я напортачил в коде, ткните носом и по возможности поясните в чем я не прав?

результатом на введенный номер документа должна быть строчка с именем и фамилией

```
documents = [
{"type": "passport", "number": "2207 876234", "name": "Василий Гупкин"},
{"type": "invoice", "number": "11-2", "name": "Геннадий Покемонов"},
{"type": "insurance", "number": "10006", "name": "Аристарх Павлов"}
]

people = input("Введите номер документа, чтобы найти человека которому он принадлежит: ")
for docs in documents:
  for k, v in docs.items():
    if v == people:
      print(docs["name"])
    else:
      print("По данному номеру документа не найден ни один человек в базе.")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Они срабатывают не вместе. Они срабатывают на разных итерациях. На первой итерации k равно "type", v равно "passport". Условие не выполнено, выполняем else. И т.д. В итоге из 9 итераций условие выполнено только 1 раз (или даже ни разу). Поэтому и получается на выходе 8 строк из else, и одна строка из if.

Вообще нет необходимости проверять каждый ключ, нужно сразу проверять number:

```
for docs in documents:
    if docs["number"] == people:
        print(docs["name"])
        break
else:
    print("По данному номеру документа не найден")
```

Comment: Спасибо за этот исчерпывающий и наглядный ответ. Искал медь, а нашел золото) Теперь хоть примерно понял насчет итерации и зонирования запроса.

Answer (score 0):

Вот эту часть "print("По данному номеру документа не найден ни один человек в базе.")" нужно выполнить тогда, когда уже весь цикл пройден (т. е. проверены все документы), и документ не найден. Обычно это делается так: если документ наден, то устанавливают признак и выходят из цикла. Потом проверяют признак и выводят сообщение о том, что ничего не найдено.

Можно использовать конструкцию [for/else](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html), как раз для таких случаев:

```
for item in container:
    if search_something(item):
        # Found it!
        process(item)
        break
else:
    # Didn't find anything..
    not_found_in_container()
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
documents = [
{"type": "passport", "number": "2207 876234", "name": "Василий Гупкин"},
{"type": "invoice", "number": "11-2", "name": "Геннадий Покемонов"},
{"type": "insurance", "number": "10006", "name": "Аристарх Павлов"}
]

people = input("Введите номер документа, чтобы найти человека которому он принадлжит: ")
isPrinted = False;
for docs in documents:
    if people == docs["number"]:
      print(docs["name"])
      isPrinted = True;

if isPrinted == False:
    print("По данному номеру документа не найден ни один человек в базе")
```

Так?